# what's wrong with the cvUndistortPoints

Tags: opencv

```
        float  k[]={1531.49,0,1267.78,0,1521.439,952.078,0,0,1};
    float  d[]={-0.27149,0.15384,0.0046,-0.0026};

    CvMat camera1=cvMat( 3, 3, CV_32FC2, k );
    CvMat distCoeffs1=cvMat(1,4,CV_32FC2,d);
    const int npoints = 4; // number of point specified 

// Points initialization. 
// Only 2 ponts in this example, in real code they are read from file.

float input_points[npoints][4] = {{0,0}, {2560, 1920}}; // the rest will be set to 0

CvMat * src = cvCreateMat(1, npoints, CV_32FC2);
CvMat * dst = cvCreateMat(1, npoints, CV_32FC2);

// fill src matrix
float * src_ptr = (float*)src->data.ptr;
for (int pi = 0; pi < npoints; ++pi) {
    for (int ci = 0; ci < 2; ++ci) {
        *(src_ptr + pi * 2 + ci) = input_points[pi][ci];
    }
}

cvUndistortPoints(src, dst, &camera1, &distCoeffs1);
```

I hope to use the cvUndistortPoints function .And used the example code to test.When I used the VS2012 to run,it dosen't work.It says“src.size dosen't match the dst.size".For I am a rookie in OpenCV.Can someone help me?
Thank you.
the result of runing by vs2012[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOTSL.jpg)

Comment: please avoid using opencv's legacy c-api.

Answer (score 1):

again, **please** use opencv's c++ api, not the deprecated c one:

```
Mat_<float> cam(3,3); cam << 1531.49,0,1267.78,0,1521.439,952.078,0,0,1;
Mat_<float> dist(1,5); dist <<-0.27149,0.15384,0.0046,-0.0026;

const int npoints = 4; // number of point specified 

// Points initialization. 
// Only 2 ponts in this example, in real code they are read from file.
Mat_<Point2f> points(1,npoints);
points(0) = Point2f(0,0);
points(1) = Point2f(2560, 1920);

Mat dst; // leave empty, opencv will fill it.
undistortPoints(points, dst, cam, dist);

cerr << dst;
```

---

```
[-0.90952414, -0.69702172, 0.92829341, 0.69035494, -0.90952414, -0.69702172, -0.90952414, -0.69702172]
```

Comment: oh,sorry not to notice that.I think the dst variable should have 4 Four elements.As you can see ,the result may be wrong.  could you help me?